# Spring boot controller structure (dependency injection problem)

Tags: spring-boot

There is something I want to do structurally while creating a controller.

Is it ok to implement `@autowired` as below?

```
@Controller
class myController{

@autowired
MyComponent1 myComponent1;

public void myfunc(){
myComponent1.init();
myComponent1.excite();
}

}
```

I am wondering if myComponent1, created in a singleton, is not a problem with concurrency.

If lock myfunc, it will be too slow.

```
@Controller
class myController{

public void myfunc(){
Mybeen mybeen = SpringApplicationContext.getBean("myComponent1", myData); 
mybeen.init();
mybeen.excite();
}
}

@scope("prototype")
@Component("myComponent1")
class myComponent1{
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

`@Component`, but it gives `@scope (prototype)` to work on a new non-singleton object.

However, there is a problem in that it creates a new myComponent1 object for every request.

Question 1.

Which way is right? Is there any other way?

Question 2.

If `@Component` has `@scope ("prototype")`, is it not different from the object created by new, not Component?

Question 3.

Each request is handled by a new thread. I do not need to create a thread pool in that structure, right?

Comment: why `myComponent1` as prototype? and `singleton` will not have any effect on `concurrency`

Comment: Would not it be a problem if `myfunc()` is called many times at the same time?

Comment: every thread has it's own stack, if you are updating any instance variables the concurrency will be a problem